# Can't remotely play music to iPhone since update to WatchOS 4

Tags: music, apple-watch, watchos

I have an Apple Watch Series 2, and I recently updated the OS to the 4th version. Previously, I could remotely listen music. Since I don't have bluetooth headphones, I was using the Apple Watch just to give the command to play music on the iPhone, which is fine for me. But since the update, now it doesn't play my music on the iPhone, and it asks me to connect any bluetooth headphones.

What if I want to listen music without bluetooth headphones?